# How do I put an image in the bootstrap 3 navbar instead of the brand text?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, navigation, responsive-design

I am building my first responsive web with bootstrap3 and all is fine except I can't put the nav where I want. When the screen resizes it moves and with mobile screens worse. I couldn't find any instructions in using an image in the navbar instead of text..

Comment: You don't add things to the bottom of an image. An image is an image, you would put an image in the navbar. http://stackoverflow.com/a/20859774/1004312. Learn more about CSS, html, and responsive design:

    http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/05/29/useful-glossaries-for-web-designers-and-developers/
    http://www.cssbasics.com/
    http://www.htmldog.com/guides/css/beginner/
    http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-to-responsive-web-design
    http://www.splio.com/responsive/
    http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/responsivedesign/
    http://getbootstrap.com/ - Read the docs!

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#examples look at the code in the examples for positioning options. Look at the comment above for how to put an image in the navbar.

Comment: I edited your question. You need to post a jSFiddle, bootply, CodePen, or JSBin with your css and html and any jQuery(if applicable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<img id="my-img" src="">
    <nav></nav>
</img>

<style>
    #my-img{
        position: relative;
    }
    #my-img nav{
        position:absolute;
        bottom:0;
    }
</style>
```

you'll want to position the image relatively and position the nav bar within the img absolutely.

Answer (score 0):

In the navbar header , use a link of class .navbar-brand and  insert your image inside of it. also, declare your image to be responsive as shown in the example below.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" style="border:0px;margin:0px;">
    <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color:#175FAF;">

        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/logo.jpg" alt="logo" class="img-responsive"></a>
        </div>


    </div>
</nav>
```